# Why do you write "occurred" but "listened"?

Tags: verbs, past-tense, doubled-consonants

The past tense of *to occur* is *occurred* (not *occured*), but the past tense of *to listen* is *listened* (not *listenned*).

Why? What is the general rule that is applied to make the past tense of a verb?

Comment: Just a side note: this is not limited to verbs. Note that the consonant is doubled in *bigger*, *hipper*, *thinner*, but not in *neater*, *weirder*, *broader*.

Comment: English spelling is so inconsistent that any answer is going to be pretty useless, because you can't really predict anything reliably.  I think the best answer is that it has to do with vowel quality (particularly short v. long), but doubling is often not applied.  There is *coming* and *homing* and *bombing* and *combing*, *living* and *diving*, etc.  (I am not saying the observation isn't interesting.)

Comment: @Kosmonaut: In the specific case, there is a reason because you write _occurred_, _barred_, and _listened_. On _English Grammar_ I found a "rule" described with words that are different from the ones used by Shinto Serlock; if I apply one or the other "rule", I obtain the same result. _Come_ is an irregular verb; _live_ is a regular verb, but it doesn't follow the schema CVC (or, following the rule I read, it's a single syllable word, and its last two letters are not a vowel and a consonant).

Comment: If there were two different verbs, *listen* and *listene*, then indeed the past of *listen* would probably be *listenned* to distinguish it from *listened* which would be the past of *listene*.  But, since we have no verb *listene*, there is no reason to double this *n*.

Answer (score 4):

*Occur* has its stress on the final syllable (o-CUR) but *listen* (LIS-en) has its stress on the first syllable. If the verb ends in the pattern *consonant-vowel-consonant*, the final consonant is doubled in the case of verbs like re**fer** and oc**cur** and be**gin** where the stress is on the final syllable (re**ferr**er, re**ferr**ing, re**ferr**ed, oc**curr**ence, oc**curr**ed, be**ginn**ing), or one syllable words (big -> bigger, sin -> sinner) but not in the case of verbs like **list**en or **brok**er (listened, listener, brokered, etc.), where the stress is non-final.

Comment: ... except in *barred*, *stirred*, *spurred*...

Comment: @Timwi you are right.

Comment: It’s a shame you edited this out of your answer because I think it is an interesting question. Why do *barred* etc. double the *r*, but *cleared*, *poured* and *roared* don’t? My guess is that it probably has something to do with vowel length in Middle English, or these words used to be bisyllabic (as indicated by the use of two vowel letters), but I would only be speculating.

Comment: @Timwi: the answer was wrong, so it needed editing.

Comment: _Bar_, and _clear_ contain a single syllable, while _occur_ is a two syllables word. It seems there are two rules that are applied depending on the number of syllables.

Comment: @Timwi: in German, the consonant letter is doubled if the preceding vowel sound is short, suggesting that your guess is not far off.

Comment: @Shinto Sherlock: I am referring to the comment made from Timwi, not your answer.

Comment: @Timwi: I'd tend to agree that it probably has something to do with vowel length. *Bar* is from O.Fr. *barre* while *bare* is from O.E. *bær,* a long-short distinction, and though I can't say anything about the rare *stire* (a possibly extinct variety of apple) and nonexistent *spure,* all of *clear, pour,* and *roar* had long vowels in Middle English.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it's to retain pronunciation. If you don't double the ending consonant, it will be ok-cured (occured) instead of occur-ed (occurred), buy-ger (biger) instead of big-er (bigger), bay-red (bared) instead of bar-ed (barred), etc.

Seems intuitive and natural to me, though I can't confirm. If I'm right, the general rule would be not to double unless pronunciation changes.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is due to the consonant letter (r) which comes at the end of the word *occur.* Based on what I studied, if the word ends with a consonant letter and before it comes a vowel letter, we should double the end letter in the past tense such as *occurred,* whereas in the word *listen* we shoudn't double the last letter because this is an irregular case. If the word has a primary stress on the left part, we should double the last letter: for example *occur* the primary stress occurs in the left part of the word (*oc'cur*) whereas in the word *listen* the premary stress occurs in the right part of the word (*listen'*) so we shoudn't double the last letter.

Comment: Hello. I have corrected a few spelling mistakes in your post; I hope you don't mind. There are still some problems with what you say. I think you've switched around the position of the stress: in "occur," the stress occurs on the right syllable (*cur*) and in "listen," the stress occurs on the left syllable (*lis*).