# Why is "happened" spelled with a single "n"?

Tags: doubled-consonants

I've seen the words

> - plan -> planned, planning
> - begin -> beginning

Why is "happen" different and why is "happenning" an incorrect spelling?

Comment: What happenned with *happened*?

Comment: *Listened, christened, chiseled, fastened, brightened, enlightened, piloted, deepened, ripened, sharpened, smartened, glistened, shortened, opened...* *Happened* is no different. That's the rule, not an exception. And it is, for a change, a rather logical, simple, and obvious rule. We have [prior questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2104/why-do-you-write-occurred-but-listened) on it, and it's even [up on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#Doubled_consonants).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference between *planned*, *penned*, *beginning* which have double *n's*, and *happening* with a single *n* is the *stressed syllable*.

When the syllable that ends in *n* is stressed, we double the *n* if another syllable starting with a vowel sound follows it. If we didn't double it, we might feel like elongating the vowel sound of the syllable ending with *n*.

When the syllable is *not* stressed, the vowel sound is usually reduced to a *schwa*, and we don't seem to have the tendency to try and elongate that sound.

Other examples of an unstressed syllable ending with an *n* would be *ripen* -> *ripening* or *open* -> *opening*.