# Why is "batting" spelled with two t's, but "combating" spelled with one?

Tags: verbs, orthography, conjugation, doubled-consonants

The "bating" in "combating" is pronounced the exact same way as "batting".  It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: *Combatting* is spelled with two t's in British English.

Comment: Bating (with a bat) would need to be disambiguated from bating (to set a trap), but with *com* in front of it, it needs nothing more.

Comment: @Jim - I never heard of bating a trap (baiting, yes), but I'm no hunter.

Comment: Have you seen [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour)? It's a great site for basic questions about the English language.

Comment: @medica- you are so right...  If I'd come at that word from a different direction I would have known that..  let's go with "fluttering of a birds wings from fear or in an attempt to escape" instead.

Comment: @medica Bating (from *bate*) and baiting would have the same pronunciation... However, Juju we do have the expression ["bated breath"](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-bai1.htm), which means to hold one's breath in anticipation.

Comment: If you could provide a tiny, tiny bit of research, a dictionary reference, examples where the single consonant is doubled, then this could become a gem of a question. It just lacks detail and evidence.

Comment: @CharlE But is it really? *Combating* seems to be the usual spelling in both [BrE](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/?c=bnc&q=46226129) and [AmE](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=46226158).

Comment: @snailboat According to Oxford (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/combat) both are OK, but I would never use a single T.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do you write "occurred" but "listened"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2104/why-do-you-write-occurred-but-listened)

Comment: "Bating (with a bat) would need to be disambiguated from bating (to set a trap), but with com in front of it, it needs nothing more. " -- even if it weren't based on a misspelling, to call this logic absurd would be too kind. To make any sense of it at all, it has to be taken as claiming that the reason that "combating" isn't spelled "combatting" is that there's no such word as "combate" ... which is complete nonsense that doesn't address the question at all. And the reason that "batting" is spelled as it is has nothing to do with resolving an ambiguity.

Comment: Bear in mind that "batting" is also a type of cotton lining.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, if the base ends in a single consonant represented by a single consonant letter, the letter is doubled before suffixes beginning with a vowel, subject though to the base being stressed on its final syllable. Monosyllabic bases do of course have the stress on the final syllable and hence always satisfy that requirement: "fat"/"fatt.er"/"fatt.est" ; "bat"/ "batt.ed"/"batt.ing"and so on.

But the verb "combat" can be stressed on either syllable so the suffixed forms are spelled with or without doubling: "combated"/"combatted"; "combating"/"combatting".

Answer (score 2):

Normally consonant doubling (CD) occurs after short stressed vowels,
and after long stressed vowels + r (-ar/er/or/ur) as in to prefer, preferred, to star/starring, but to stare/staring.

CD with unstressed syllables is a kind of grey area. It occurs regularly after -el as in to travel, BrE travelling, AmE traveling, and after -al as in to signal, BrE signalling, AmE signaling.

Sometimes it occurs after p as in to kidnap/kidnapping, to worship/worshipping, but not in to develop/developing.

Unstressed syllables ending with -t normally have no CD. But to combat is a special case. Pons has to combat and combatting/combating. Perhaps the CD is occasional in analogy to to bat/batting. Oald, Collins, McMillan don't mention CD.

Comment: The verb "to combat" may be pronounced with stress on the second syllable. I assume that is why some dictionaries list the forms with consonant doubling. The vowels "ar/er/or/ur" are only long vowels phonetically; in the writing system, they are treated as short vowels followed by a consonant. With "kidnapping" and "worshipping," I'm not sure if the "p" is as relevant as the secondary stress. "Programming" also has consonant doubling and secondary stress on the last syllable. But from this point of view, it is odd that "combat" doesn't have doubling.

Comment: Maybe people for some reason perceive "kidnap" and "worship" as compound words. There are derivatives of "kidnap" like "dognap." In English compounds, it seems like we often have CD even when the last syllable doesn't have the primary stress (e.g. "bullshitting").

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the English UK spelling should be combatting in all cases, according to spelling rules, as someone pointed out above. This word is no "exception to the rule": the confusion stems simply from erroneous MS Word spellcheck, which for this word has US settings even when you are writing in English (United Kingdom)...

Comment: Your answer would benefit from a sourced referrence being [edit]ed into it.

Comment: The trouble is that if different spelling variants are available, people are free to choose which variant they prefer no matter where they live. Admittedly it is more reasonable to subscribe to local mores, but this is not a rule.